# Twilio outgoing call is not working, it's terminated automatically

Tags: android, twilio

How we can  call app to app and app to phone by using Twilio android sdk. The main problem is that our call is terminated automatically  when call is initialized.This is the php side script for outgoing calls , but outgoing call is not working, call terminated automatically when in intialized state.

```
outgoing.php
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
include 'db.php';
require 'twilio-twilio-php-788b98f/Services/Twilio.php';
require('twilio-twilio-php-788b98f/Services/Twilio/Capability.php');

$accountSid = '';
$authToken = '';
$applicationSid =''; 
// Twilio REST API version
$version = "2010-04-01";



// put a phone number you've verified with Twilio to use as a caller ID  number
$From = $_REQUEST['From'];   // Dialer Number Twilio User or Non Twilio User

// put your default Twilio Client name here, for when a phone number isn't given
$To = $_REQUEST['To'];   // Dialer Number Twilio User or Non Twilio User


$client = new Services_Twilio($accountSid, $authToken, $version);


    // Initiate a new outbound call
    $call = $client->account->calls->create(
        $From, // The number of the phone initiating the call
        $To, // The number of the phone receiving call
        'http://sitelink.coml/basic-call.php'); 
       $a= $call->sid;
?>

  basiccall.php
<Response>
<?php
    // if the From is from "client:basic" (e.g. the iOS App), redirect to the normal
    // quickstart URL to say a nice "Welcome to Twilio Client" message.
    // Otherwise, if the From is a phone number, have it call the client named "basic"
    // to dial into the iOS app.
    $from = isset($_REQUEST["From"]) ? $_REQUEST["From"] : "";
    if ( $from == "client:basic" )
    { // redirect to the sample app URL
?>
    <Say>Welcome to Twilio Client.  You have successfully made a call from your i o s application!</Say>
<?php
    }
    else if (preg_match("/^\+?\d+$/", $from)) // (zero or one '+' chars, then one or more digits)
    { // else if it's from a phone number, dial the client named "basic"
?>
    <Say>Call from Beckon Delve</Say>
    <Dial>
        <Client>basic</Client>
    </Dial>
<?php
    } 
?>
</Response>
```

Comment: Any chance you might add some code here? I wonder if it is unlikely that anyone will work out the problem based on this brief post.

Comment: can u send me php script for that

Comment: No - Stack Overflow is not a place where you can ask people to work for free. If you can ask a specific and detailed question that indicates what kind of error you are getting, you should be able to get the right kind of assistance.

Comment: i will add the code check that

Comment: "outgoing call is not working" - are there any logs in a Twilio control panel? Do all of your calls return any error conditions?

Comment: the status of the call is complete

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Is sitelink.com the URL you are trying to build this feature for? As you have a typo in the URL: http://sitelink.coml/basic-call.php

Otherwise, if the call is failing, there should be logs in the [Monitor section of the Twilio account dashboard](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/monitor/alerts).

Alternatively, is your `preg_match` not matching anything when you call? If it doesn't match anything, Twilio will just get an empty `<Response>` and hang up the call. Probably best to look into whether that is working correctly too.

Sorry I can't answer your question exactly. Hope this helps though.

Comment: is there any bug in above  php script, why the call is terminated automatically when initialize, can you  explain it to me.

Comment: I'm trying to help discover what is wrong. Have you checked the things I asked about? Could you tell me the answers?

Comment: hey yes we get the empty response

Comment: there are http reterival failure ,http connection failure, these type of error o get on app monitor

Comment: Ok, so Twilio can't reach your service. How are you making this available online?